# Clear empty values from JSON (actually array) field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a table, in this table I have a JSON field. In this field I store arrays with some data. For example:

1. ["a", "", "c"]
2. ["", "", ""]
3. ["a", "b", "c"]

I need to clear this field from empty values and get:

1. ["a", "c"]
2. null
3. ["a", "b", "c"]

Then update the filed values.

Comment: `REPLACE('[]',NULL,REPLACE('"", ','',columnJson))` like this?

Comment: I try it in this way: REPLACE('[]',NULL,REPLACE('"", ','','["a", "", "c"]')). Gives me syntax error

Comment: Share all the sentence, and gives us the syntax error-

Comment: [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('[]',NULL,REPLACE('"", ','','["a", "", "c"]'))' at line 1. The sentence is just: REPLACE('[]',NULL,REPLACE('"", ','','["a", "", "c"]'))

Comment: @pepe_botika69, What is your MySQL version?

Comment: You have to execute an `UPDATE`... replacing the column with that sentence

Comment: @Roy Sorry, my error. But Now I empty my field. I used: UPDATE table SET emails = REPLACE('[]',NULL,REPLACE('"", ','',emails)) WHERE id = 1; I had field emails = '["a", "", "c"], after i ran the command I got emails = null

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy MySql version 5.7

Comment: It looks like I found the problem. The order of the arguments. REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement ) . I will test.

Comment: @pepe_botika69 Yep, sorry, my fault. Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7da50/4/0)

Comment: @Roy yes, that is the sentence without errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [REPLACE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php):

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(emails,'"", ',''), '[""]','null')
```

Working example here in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7da50/4/0)

> @PaulSpiegel:
>   
> Doesn't work for `["", "b", ""]`

**Solved:**

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(emails,'"", ',''), '[""]','null'),', ""','')
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `["", "b", ""]` - [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e77da1/1)

Comment: That wasn't an option.

Comment: If you just want something, that only works for the given sample data, then you could just hardcode the result.